# Webform Serial - Serial Numbers updating after editing submission

Tags: webforms

I am using webform serial to generate tracking numbers for webform submission.

If I edit a submission the serial number auto increments to the next available number. How can I stop this from happening and have the number locked - even when I edit a submission?

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest placing an issue on the project page-it seems like it would be a common issue-but you've already [done so](https://www.drupal.org/node/2471132). If the maintainer doesn't respond, you could look at the code yourself to figure out why and [create a patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/707484) for it.